# Linq statement created in vb.net not working in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert the following in C# and can't figure it out.

```
Dim query = From p In products Select p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.ProductCategory Distinct
```

Is this trying to return an anonymous object?

Here is my attempt in C#:

```
var query = from p in products select p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.ProductCategory distinct;
```

The error I get is: Implicitly typed local variables cannot have multiple declarators.

Comment: Yes I will show my attempt.

Comment: maybe because you wrote `from **b** in products` instead of p?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when adding it to here. Should this be working in C# because it errors in intellisense and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you using "var query" twice in the C# code?

Comment: Looks like you need to go read an intro tutorial on writing LINQ queries in C#, given how far off your implementation is.

Comment: I recommend you to download and check the samples of the great app [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) It has plenty of examples in C# and VB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `Distinct` method, over an the implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`. It is not part of query expression syntax. Try this:

```
var query = (from p in products 
            select new { 
                      p.ProductId, 
                      p.ProductName, 
                      p.ProductCategory 
             }).Distinct();
```

PS: I did not test it to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed. I have no idea why in VB.NET that just works the way it is. Also not sure why everyone is downgrading this post. What could I have done to make it better?

Comment: `Distinct` is absolutely a part of LINQ, it just isn't a part of the query expression syntax in C#.

Comment: It is what I would say. I correct my anwser. Thank you @Servy